# Whats datatypes can be used with enum in c programming and what is the size of enum?

Tags: c

I don't know what datatypes can be used with enum in c programming

Comment: Check out the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enumeration is a set of named integer constant values (C 2018 6.2.5 16).

An enumeration constant has type `int` (C 2018 6.4.4.3 2).

An enumerated type is compatible with `char` or a signed or unsigned integer type (C 2018 6.7.2.2 4). The choice is implementation-defined, which means it is up to your C compiler.

Thus, the size of an enumeration type depends on your C compiler.

For example, in `enum color { red, green, blue };`:

- Each of `red`, `green`, and `blue` is an enumeration constant. It is a constant of type `int`, and its size is that of an `int` in your C implementation.
- The enumeration type, `enum color`, could be `char`, `signed short`, `unsigned int`, or other possibilities.

Comment: So the enumeration type `enum color` could be different from type of `red`? Why is that?

Comment: @Ayxan: I cannot speak to the history or the deliberations of the C standard committee in this, but C does have a history of using `int` for expressions in general, while the stored object is more specific. For example, when objects of type `char` or `short` are used in expressions, they are converted to `int`, the expression is evaluated, and the result, if it is stored in an object, is converted to the type of the object. So the enumeration constants are merely acting as values, and hence they are `int`, while the enumeration type itself is a more specific object.

Comment: can enum have a float and double data types?

Comment: @Nikithaniki: No. Integers only.

Answer (score 0):

The value assigned to enum names must be some integeral constant, i.e., the value must be in range from minimum possible integer value to maximum possible integer value.
Please visit this page:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumeration-enum-c/.